How do I debug intermittent import issues when using python virtualenv?
Python library imports are taking minutes on my computer when I am in an environment created by virtualenv. This intermittent problem started for me in June and has continued until now (October), and I am at a loss for what the issue is.
It appears to be the same issue as Common Python libraries take 'forever' to import and some time-out, which never received an answer.
The issue:
Sometimes when I import libraries (as basic as numpy or pandas), it takes minutes to import.  At first I thought the import was entirely stuck, but when I run a script with the verbose option, I see that the library is being imported, just extremely slowly. After the first slow import, subsequent ones import as quickly as they should (most of the time).
Details:

This happens on my personal MacOS Sonoma 14.6.1 computer.
This has happened for environments that I have created with Python 3.10.11 and Python 3.11.5. I have deleted and recreated an environment with virtualenv (no change).  I have used conda on my computer as well, and have noticed that an environment created with micromamba can experience similar delays, though not as extreme as with virtualenv. I have wondered if there is some sort of conflict between package managers, but I don't know how to check.
This most frequently occurs when I am running scripts in this environment for the first time in a day, but sometimes I would have been running scripts for hours and then this issue re-emerges without warning.
Once the first import happens, then subsequent imports happen as quickly as they should.  I have noticed that if I am trying to run a script in one terminal (e.g. in VScode) and the import is stuck, I can open a new terminal, activate the same environment, open Python interactively, and try importing the same library.  It will still be stuck, but as soon as the library imports in that second terminal, the imports also become instantaneous in the first terminal (i.e. this is a problem across my computer, not just related to opening a new terminal).
I have already tried creating a new virtual environment with the same requirements.txt file, and I have encountered the same issue. Of course, I have restarted Otherwise, I am at a loss for how to debug this.  It seems like it gets stuck on importing specific libraries, like pandas (pandas==2.2.0) and bokeh (bokeh==3.4.1).

How can I figure out what the issue is, especially when there is no error for me to debug? Any suggestions would be helpful - I am not very familiar with computer hardware or all of the details of how these imports occur, so I would appreciate any guidance for how to proceed.
Example requirements.txt
_
Here are the requirements for an example virtual environment that exhibits this issue (Python 3.10.11):
Cython==3.0.8
pandas==2.2.0
numpy==1.26.3
scipy==1.13.0
cvxopt==1.3.2
statsmodels==0.14.1
Flask==3.0.1
bokeh==3.4.1


can you share your requirements.txt?

@16171413 yes, just updated my post with the requirements

please post some details about your environment: O.S.,  is this on a VM? is the filesystem mounted in a different way? If Linux, would you know the filesystem?

@jsbueno I am using macOS Sonoma, on my personal computer. The environment was created with virtualenv, but I also have conda and micromamba installed on my computer. Let me know if there is other information that would be helpful to know!
